# Scrapy: save data (items) in a CSV file in lowercase without losing the encoding

Tags: python, string, scrapy

I want to save my items in a CSV file in lowercase. I tried this:

```
iNomVin= map(unicode.strip, res.select('//div[@class="pro_detail_tit"]//div[@class="pro_titre"]/h1/text()').extract())
item ["nomVin"]= str(iNomVin).lower()
```

But it gave me this bad result in the CSV file:

```
[u'ch\xe2teau belair 2002']
```

How can I transform my items to lowercase without losing the UTF-8 encoding? [Link to my program](https://gist.github.com/XeroxGH/f18a029e3df4362080c9).

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to transform my items on lowercase without losing the utf-8 encoding  ?

Comment: If you want an unicode string encoded as UTF-8 try to use `str.encode("utf-8")`. Internally Python tries to be encoding-agnostic.

Comment: it dosn't work :(
the result produced : 
[u'ch\xe2teau belair 2002']
I want to get this result :
château belair 2002

Comment: You'll have to print it - that's just a representation made for debugging.

Comment: this a piece of my program:
 x= map(unicode.strip, res.select('//div[@class="pro_detail_tit"]//div[@class="pro_titre"]/h1/text()').extract())
iNomVin= str(x).lower()
item ["nomVin"]=iNomVin.encode("utf-8")